# How to change the background of pic?

Tags: post-processing, background

I want to change the whole background.I have installed many apps for this purpose that  demands to erase that part of pic.and i can't do it well..I think no one can do this well.I just want that thing on applying that it will really look like, u are at that place..no erasing no croping.do u know about such app?this all look unreal
[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you have an example image? What have you tried so far? When you say "app" are you referring to an application for a mobile device or for a certain desktop operating system?

Comment: I have edited now look plz

Answer (score 0):

Adobe Photoshop Mix for both iOS and Android seems to be exactly what you are looking for. One of the features is:

> Cut out and combine pictures

iOS link:
https://appsto.re/us/2PcX0.i

Google Play Store link:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.adobe.photoshopmix&hl=en